# Вывод customfields внутри модуля Virtuemart Product

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Есть необходимость вывести "дополнительные (настраиваемые) поля" товара, непосредственно в модуле в mod_virtuemart_product. Поискал много информации в интернете, нашел пару способов но не один не помог:

```
<?php echo shopFunctionsF::renderVmSubLayout('customfields',array('product'=>$product));?>
```

И такой:

```
<?php print_r($product->customfields);?>
```

И результатом было то, что ничего не происходило вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Я делал в кастомном модуле через банальный запрос:

```
$db=JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery('SELECT DISTINCT(custom_value) AS cfield FROM #__virtuemart_product_customfields WHERE virtuemart_custom_id=1'); 
$result=$db->loadObjectList();
foreach($result as $cfields) echo $cfields->cfield ;
```